# ngx-charts-bubble-chart respond slow

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I was doing bubble ploting with ngx-charts. Things are working, but when I was trying to do with >2000 data points, it respond very slow. Did I miss anything there?

Splitting data might be the last thing I want to try in this case. Is there any trick to speed it up?
Thanks.

```
 <ngx-charts-bubble-chart
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [view]=[1200,800]
    [results]="bubbleData"
    [xAxis]="showXAxis"
    [yAxis]="showYAxis"
    [legend]="showLegend"
    [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
    [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
    [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
    [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
    [minRadius]="minRadius"
    [maxRadius]="maxRadius"
    (select)="onSelect($event)"
    (activate)="onActivate($event)"
    (deactivate)="onDeactivate($event)">
    </ngx-charts-bubble-chart>
```